# Using 'WhatsApp' as a verb

Tags: verbs, formality

[Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/whatsapptm_2) presents 'WhatsApp' as a verb and noun.

> **WhatsApp**™ verb
>
> /ˈwɒtsæp/,  /ˌwɒtsˈæp/
>
> /ˈwʌtsæp/,  /ˌwʌtsˈæp/
>
> [transitive, intransitive]
>
> WhatsApp (somebody) to send a message, photo or video using the
> WhatsApp service.
>
> *I WhatsApped Abigail yesterday to let her know what had happened.*
>
> *She spent most of the evening WhatsApping and taking selfies.*

Is it acceptable to use 'WhatsApp' in formal contexts as a verb?

Comment: Please be more specific what is intended by "formal contexts". Are you referring to an academic paper, an essay, an article in a journal,  newspaper/magazine. In the field of business, technology, education, linguistics etc

Comment: What are your specific concerns? It's common to use product names as verbs, but it may not be appropriate everywhere. Style guides may object to it. Maybe you're worried about being sued for trademark infringement (which is a legal question). Or is the capitalization a concern? You could use "to contact by WhatsApp" if you want to be more formal, or the verb "to instant message".

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Yes it includes all the contexts you mentioned, especially academic paper.

Comment: Personally, in an academic paper I wouldn't use it as a verb there's absolutely no good reason to when you can say: "People who use [the instant messaging] WhatsApp...blah, blah, blah”

Comment: Let me think about it and I'll Whatsapp you my thoughts later, or if the discussion becomes too long I'll just print it and FedEx it to you. I'll be sure to Xerox myself a copy first, of course..... Product names frequently become integrated into the language, as both verbs and nouns.

Comment: If you're not sure, just Google it. ;)  Jokes aside, I think this particular verb is more common in some regions than others. I wouldn't suggest using it in a formal setting unless you see other people in the same formal setting already doing so.

Comment: I haven't facebooked anyone yet.

Comment: Closing this question is unjustified. The answer is not a matter of opinion. There are precedents in usage that stand regardless of discussion of the minutiae of whether the usage applies in all circumstances. By closing such questions we demean the subtlety and depth of analysis of which this site is capable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don’t like it (merely my prejudice) but I suggest it is acceptable in the same way that other nouns relating to communication became verbs.

*Telephone* and *phone* were nouns for the device; they are now also verbs.  “I will phone on Friday”

*Text* was a noun for a set of words; it is now also a verb.
“Please text me the election result”

*Google* was a name for a company; it is now also a verb.
“Please google **Anthimeria**”

> [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/anthimeria)
>
> anthimeria:
>
> the usage of a word in a new grammatical form, most often the usage of a noun as a verb

Comment: Don't fight it too hard. It's better to say "I'll WhatsApp you the photo" than "I'll text you the photo", which is sometimes heard, nonsensical on the face of it, and wrong because "text" (v) = SMS != MMS

Comment: @ChrisH Why not simply use *send*? If you're both on WhatsApp, it could be assumed that you'll send it in the regular and easy method

Comment: @GammaGames "send" (or something more specific like "forward") would be my preferred option in general. If starting from one method (e.g. WhatsApp, email) "send" would tend to mean sticking with the same method - solved. *But*: If starting in one medium, perhaps speech, using the name of the channel makes sense, so they know where to watch out for it - or to avoid the hassle of transferring a photo from an email attachment to a WhatsApp message or vice versa.  BTW your "WhatsApp" = "the regular & easy method" is an assumption  that may not always hold even when both contacts use it

Comment: @ChrisH It's not? Everyone I know uses "text" for MMS, well and Telegram, WhatsApp, etc...

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- OK "text" for text via any of those channels makes complete sense from their similarity to SMS, but "text" for non-text media, no

Comment: @ChrisH It doesn't? I'm not sure I understand your objection.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I don't have time to draw a Venn diagram, but "text" as a hypernym for *things that are text*  and *things that are most definitely not text* (like photos) shows a complete lack of logic.  That's the sort of thing that encourages people to work with screenshots of written info instead of copy-pasting the actual text), a problem we often have to deal with elsewhere on this network for example.

Comment: @ChrisH Right, but the issue isn't describing a picture as "text," but saying "I'll text you a photo" is perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- OK, I see where you're coming from and don't agree. The use you describe exists, I don't dispute that, but there's invariably a better choice of verb. I say that "text" (verb) means what you're sending should be text (noun), otherwise *to me* the use of the verb is illogical, and often unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

No, the use of WhatsApp and Google as generic verbs or nouns is not acceptable in formal English, for two reasons, in spite of the appearance of the word in a dictionary:

First, such use is subject to legal action. These are trademarked terms, and the trademark is protected (specifically, from use by another company as a name for its product) by actions the owner takes to object to its use, such as a “cease and desist” order. This is not the kind of attention you want for a formal document.

Second, such use is not precise. WhatsApp is the use of encryption in messages and voice calls, but it is not the sole application that does so, just as there are search engines for searching the World Wide Web other than Google.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_(verb) for details.

As @StuartF points out, it’s not illegal to mention the product specifically. Its use as a verb without a trademark symbol might, however, get legal attention.

Comment: It is not against trademark rules to mention a product. You think Meta (owners of WhatsApp) sue every journalist who mentions WhatsApp? Do Ford sue anyone who mentions driving a Ford? If you are using Google or WhatsApp as generic terms for search engine and instant messaging software, they may get upset, although even then there is little they can do. But using WhatsApp to actually refer to WhatsApp is fine.

Comment: @Xanne, The Oxford Lerner's Dictionaries have used the trademark symbol with the verb 'WhatsAPP; but they've not used it in their example sentences. Do you think it's safer to use a trademark symbol with the word whenever it's used as a verb?

Comment: @mahmudkpukayoor It's normal to only use the symbol the first time a trademark is referenced in a text. So leaving it out of the example sentences doesn't suggest anything in particular.

Comment: @Barmar So is it a legal requirement to use the trademark symbol with the verb 'WhatsAPP the first time you use it in any communication?

Comment: IANAL, but I AIUI, only the owner of the trademark needs to use the TM or ® symbols, as a way of announcing to others that it's not a generic term. Others may use it as a courtesy (often with a footnote indicating who the owner is), but aren't required to.